# How to iterate Multilevel Map using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-stream

I'm good with Java streams, so maybe this is not the minimal solution, but here's what I came up with using streams to get what I think you want:

Do we have DishDiet as a POJO and DishDietTest as the main class?
I am getting data as desired but how to loop it?
How to iterate Multilevel Map using Java 8 stream?
How to get print based on classification done using stream?

```java
public class DishDiet {

    private final String name;
    private final boolean vegetarian;
    private final int calories;
    private final Type type;
    private final CaloricLevel caloricLevel;

    public DishDiet(String name, boolean vegetarian, int calories, Type type, CaloricLevel caloricLevel) {
        this.name = name;
        this.vegetarian = vegetarian;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.type = type;
        this.caloricLevel = caloricLevel;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isVegetarian() {
        return vegetarian;
    }

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public CaloricLevel getCaloricLevel() {
        return caloricLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    
    public enum Type {
        MEAT, FISH, OTHER
    }

    public enum CaloricLevel {
        DIET, NORMAL, FAT
    }

}
```

```java
public class DishDietTest {

    private static List<DishDiet> getAllDishDiet() {
        return Arrays.asList(new DishDiet("pork", false, 800, DishDiet.Type.MEAT, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.FAT),
                new DishDiet("beef", false, 700, DishDiet.Type.MEAT, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.FAT),
                new DishDiet("chicken", false, 400, DishDiet.Type.MEAT, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.DIET),
                new DishDiet("french fries", true, 530, DishDiet.Type.OTHER, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.NORMAL),
                new DishDiet("rice", true, 350, DishDiet.Type.OTHER, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.DIET),
                new DishDiet("season fruit", true, 120, DishDiet.Type.OTHER, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.DIET),
                new DishDiet("pizza", true, 550, DishDiet.Type.OTHER, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.NORMAL),
                new DishDiet("prawns", false, 300, DishDiet.Type.FISH, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.DIET),
                new DishDiet("salmon", false, 450, DishDiet.Type.FISH, DishDiet.CaloricLevel.NORMAL));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<DishDiet.Type, Map<DishDiet.CaloricLevel, List<DishDiet>>> dishesByTypeCaloricLevel = getAllDishDiet()
                .stream().collect(groupingBy(DishDiet::getType, groupingBy((dish -> {
                    if (dish.getCalories() <= 400)
                        return DishDiet.CaloricLevel.DIET;
                    else if (dish.getCalories() <= 700)
                        return DishDiet.CaloricLevel.NORMAL;
                    else
                        return DishDiet.CaloricLevel.FAT;
                }

        ))));

        System.out.println(dishesByTypeCaloricLevel);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
    dishesByTypeCaloricLevel.forEach((type, innerMap) 
            -> {
                System.out.println(type);
                innerMap.forEach((cl, list)
                        -> {
                            System.out.println("    " + cl);
                            list.forEach(dd -> System.out.println("        " + dd));
                        });
            });
```

Output:

> ```
> OTHER
>     NORMAL
>         french fries
>         pizza
>     DIET
>         rice
>         season fruit
> FISH
>     NORMAL
>         salmon
>     DIET
>         prawns
> MEAT
>     FAT
>         pork
>     NORMAL
>         beef
>     DIET
>         chicken
> ```

I am not using streams for iterating and printing. I recommend that we just use the `forEach` methods of `Map` and `List`. The use is similar but a bit simpler.

> Do we have DishDiet as a POJO and DishDietTest as the main class? …

Yes, that’s fine.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much Ole V.V

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Map.Entry<DishDiet.Type, Map<DishDiet.CaloricLevel,List<DishDiet>>> t : dishesByTypeCaloricLevel.entrySet()){
    DishDiet.Type key = t.getKey();
    for (Map.Entry<DishDiet.CaloricLevel,List<DishDiet>> e : 
        t.getValue().entrySet())
        System.out.println("OuterKey:" + key + " InnerKey: " + e.getKey()+ " VALUE:" +e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).